# Running paralell threads on Powershell

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I need to execute some operation on a PS script that should be ran in parallel. Using PS Jobs is not a real option since the tasks that must be paralized depends on custom functions that are defined inside a separete Module. Although I know that I can use the *-InitializationScript* flag and import the module that contains my custom function, I think that I loose speed since importing the hole module is "time consuming" operation.

Bearing in mind all those things I'm trying launching those "tasks" in separate threads that share the runspace. My code looks like:

```
$ps = [Powershell]::Create().AddScript({ Get-CustomADDomain -dnsdomain $env: })
$threadRes = $ps.beginInvoke()
$ps.EndInvoke($threadRes)
```

The drawback of this approach is that, since I'm creating a new "powershell process" this runspace do not have my custom modules loaded and thus I'm in the same situation that I got with Jobs.

If I try to attach current runspace to the newly created $ps by using following code:

```
$ps = [Powershell]::Create()
$ps.runspace = $host.runspace
$ps.AddScript({ Get-CustomADDomain -dnsdomain $env: })
$threadRes = $ps.beginInvoke()
$ps.EndInvoke($threadRes)
```

I get an error because I'm trying to close current pipeline (bad thing).

I think my second shot is on the right way but I cannot retrieve results from the invocation of the script, or at least I'm not able to see the way to do it.

It's obvious that I must missing something so any advice you may have will be very appretiated!!!!

Comment: I'm curious about the outcome of this. I've tried to do the same thing as you for several days and failed. I've ended up using jobs, because PS just doesn't seem capable of running parallel threads.

Comment: Have you looked at [this Hey! Scripting Guy post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/09/29/weekend-scripter-max-out-powershell-in-a-little-bit-of-time-part-2.aspx)? Haven't done this myself, but it goes over what you are trying to do.

Comment: @beavel I definitely should improve my "googling" skills, that's the kind of post that I was looking for. I'm gonna try this and let you know guys :)

Comment: Have you looked at [workflows](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/26/powershell-workflows-the-basics.aspx) to get tasks running in parallel?

Comment: @alroc although your approach could be a solution, unfortunatelly I'm limited to PS 2.0 with no real option for an update to PS 3.0 :( Neverthess thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new job or runspace isn't going to inherit functions from a module that was imported into the current session. That being said, you don't have to import the entire module.  If you've got specific functions in the current session you need to have available in the job, you can add just those functions like this:

```
function test_function {'This is a test'}
function test_function2 {'This is also a test'}

$job_functions = 'test_function','test_function2'

$init = [scriptblock]::Create(
 $(foreach ($job_function in $job_functions)
  { 
@"

function $job_function 
{$((get-item function:$job_function).definition)}

"@
  }))


$init

function test_function 
{'This is a test'}

function test_function2 
{'This is also a test'}
```